# SQL Columns writing under by the other

Tags: c#, sql, database, datatables

I have a table like this:

```
 NAME        SURNAME        AGE
Julie        Franks          22
Murdock      Debian          40
```

I want to fetch these rows into notepad like this:

```
Julie
Franks
22

Murdock
Debian
40
```

How can I write the columns under by the other like the above in C#?

Comment: This is way too broad. Are you asking how to retrieve data from a table? Are you asking how to write to a file? Tell us what you've tried and how far along you are. I just about promise I, or any number of other contributors, will be able to get you to your solution. But we need some more details about what problems you're actually having.

Comment: What Matthew Haugen said, plus why would you want to do this?  Not sure what requirement you are trying to meet, it really seems odd to want this as output

Comment: if you for some reason really do want this, we will need to know what database (mysql, oracle, postgresql, etc.) is holding, or will hold, the data (you can do it in sql but the syntax would vary a little)

Comment: At my first topic i asked a question about creating merge fields on office word in c# but didt get an answer. i changed the method of question. because my app based on a Qestion and Answer will be written notepad or word document.

Comment: i dont want from you the source code. you show me a way that how can i do? im using sql database and getting datawith sqldataadapter then binding it to dataset after counting the rows then with a for loop  selecting which row or which column will be used.

Comment: Nobody is too sure what you are asking in that other question either.  Am I wrong in saying you want to create an app that fetches questions and answers into a word file?

Comment: it couldnt be so difficult for good programmers like you

Comment: what type of SQL database?  There are different types...

Comment: @Twelft ok you are right. i couldnt tell you what is my problem. but this topic is so open.

Comment: "it couldnt be so difficult for good programmers like you " flattery works. You have to give us more information Hasan...walk into a mechnaic and ask 'I want to fix a vehicle'. Any mechanic is going to ask you what type of vehicle...and they'd be as confused as we are if you said "it couldn't be so difficult for good mechanics like you".  Tried to save question

Comment: @Twelfth i have a database on sql server 2008 named TEST and have a table QuestionsAndAnswer. it has columns like this; Name,Question,Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using sql server 2008 as you say you can take this approach in sql.

A demonstration is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e917/11/0

Assuming your table structure is like:

```
create table tbl (name varchar(20), surname varchar(20), age int);

insert into tbl values ('Julie', 'Franks', 22);
insert into tbl values ('Murdock', 'Debian', 40);
```

I would add an id column for each row like so: (this will allow the query that follows to work, because the id is needed for order)

```
alter table tbl add id int identity;
```

Then run:

```
select id, name as col, 1 as ord
  from tbl
union all
select id, surname, 2 as ord
  from tbl
union all
select id, convert(varchar, age), 3 as ord
  from tbl
union all
select id, '', 4 as ord
  from tbl
 order by id, ord
```

The 'col' column shows the output as you want it.

Comment: so thanks for your response. thats what i want. i will save your sql command to a stored procedure. but i have a question. the col Column is a Temp? or will alter a column at my tbl table?

Comment: the col column is not actually stored anywhere, it's just the output of your query. if you want you can insert the result of the query into a table via select into (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp)